# CSS adjacent Siblings Overwriting each other

Tags: html, css

I've noticed when using `~` to select the siblings, the order that the rules occur in the stylesheet is causing them to overwrite one another.

What I would like is every `.test` after `.ColorBlue` to be blue and every `.test` after `.ColorRed` to be red.

The data is going to be pulled dynamically so the order of the colors will be constantly changing.

Additionally new data can be inserted dynamically so using jquery's "nextUntil" would be pretty impractical.

What am I doing wrong?

```css
.ColorBlue, .ColorBlue ~ tbody.test {
    background: blue;
}
.ColorRed, .ColorRed ~ tbody.test {
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tbody class="ColorRed">
        <tr>
            <td>red</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody class="test ">
        <tr>
            <td>test</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody class="ColorBlue">
        <tr>
            <td>blue</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody class="test ">
        <tr>
            <td>≡</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: If you only have one `.test` after each colour, use a `+` immediate sibling selector. Otherwise you'll have to fallback to `.nextUntil`, but I'm not sure why it wouldn't work with dynamically added elements if you repeat/update your selection after DOM manipulation/injection.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`+` Adjacent sibling selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#adjacent-selectors) to achieve this.

The [`~` General sibling combinator](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Selectors/combinators/general) will select **all** elements matching the selector, not just the first. It won't be overwritten by the subsequent rule as it is not more specific than the first rule.

```css
.ColorBlue, .ColorBlue + tbody.test {
    background: blue;
}
.ColorRed, .ColorRed + tbody.test {
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tbody class="ColorRed">
        <tr>
            <td>red</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody class="test ">
        <tr>
            <td>test</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody class="ColorBlue">
        <tr>
            <td>blue</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody class="test ">
        <tr>
            <td>≡</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Since it's going to be dynamically generated the number would vary, so the + selector wouldn't be ideal.

Comment: Then you would have to put each section within a container so no other sections are affected. But that doesn't really make sense when using a table. So this is the only solution that will work. Unless you add `.ColorRed` and `.ColorBlue` to each `.text` element. This can be done when you're dynamically inserting the data

Comment: The way you're creating the table doesn't really make sense in terms of displaying tabular data. Could you [make a gist](//gist.github.com) of some actual generated tabular data and post a link here? Then I could give you a better answer.